# Does ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed() have UB if I use 16 bit Indices with an Offset?

Tags: directx, directx-11, direct3d, direct3d11

`ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed()` has a parameter `StartIndexLocation`, which adds a value to each Index when drawing.

What happens if I use 16 bit Indices ?

The highest value 16 bit can represent is 65535. What If my Draw Call has 10000 vertices and I use a `StartIndexLocation` of 65000 ? Will it invoke UB?

Comment: But the parameters are 32 bit UINT, so your 16 bit values will be promoted to 32 bit before addition happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StartIndexLocation is not a byte-position, but an Index position. Cross reference [DirectX Index Buffer -> Start of Index Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549262/directx-index-buffer-start-of-index-buffer)

So the maximum StartIndexLocation is not related to the stride of the Index Buffer.